# Convert character value to hexa in java

Tags: java

I have method to covert character to haxa like

```
private static String convert(char str)
    {
        StringBuffer ostr = new StringBuffer();
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(str & 0xFFFF);  
        for(int j=0; j<4-hex.length(); j++) 
            ostr.append("0");
        ostr.append(hex.toUpperCase());

        return (new String(ostr));      

    }
```

Its work fine for window but create problem for linux.
Can any one suggest me how to do same thing in linux ?

Comment: What kind of problem are you talking about?

Comment: and above all, what is "haxa"?

Comment: [As always](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints), you'll get a lot better responses if you say what output you were *expecting*, and what you *got* on Linux.  By the way, this is unlikely to be an OS-level issue; rather, it's likely to be a character encoding problem as it looks like you're making some heroic assumptions there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try, e.g.:

```
String.format("%1$04x", ('c' & 0xFFFF))
```

Check the documentation of `java.lang.String` for more details.

Cheers!